# XSS filter for an existing Java application

Tags: java, filter, xss, httpresponse

my Java coding experience is mediocre at best.  And I am trying to find out if there's a way I can implement a (XSS) filter on an existing Java web application.  I googled and found folks using the HttpServletRequestWrapper class which strips out the usual XSS suspects (<, script, > etc) on the input validation side.  But what I would like to implement is an outgoing filter which encodes characters like < to < etc. to prevent XSS on the way out from the server to the browser.  I looked up the HttpServletResponseWrapper class, but it doesn't have the getParameter methods that the HttpServletRequestWrapper does.  So, I am not sure how to extricate the form fields from the HTTP response and then encode the fields.  Is what I'm trying to do possible with the HttpServletResponseWrapper?  Or should I be using some other filter class?  Ideally, I'd like to leave the core business logic of the app alone and just encode for XSS using filters.  If this works, we have a whole bunch of other apps to fix.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I may have found an example to tweak here https://mail.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/how-to-modify-http-response-using-java-filter